# Matlab Plotting with Variable Subscripts

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

So I need to plot a function, let's say it's:  y = sin( x<sub>k</sub> )

But I can only write the matlab code like:

```
x = -pi : .1 : pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y);
```

If I try to do x<sub>k</sub>, then it cries about not knowing what `k` is. Any idea how I can plot functions with variables that contain subscripts (the subscripts are just descriptive, they don't hold any value)? Thanks

Comment: Where do you want the subscript to appear, in the plot, say the legend? 
You cannot have subscripts in the code itself and to a limited extent in symbolic expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Variables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html) cannot have subscripts. You don't have to reproduce the formula exactly in a MATLAB statement. This is fine to name variable just `x`, or `xk`, or `x_k`, etc.

On the other hand, if you have multiple vectors that you want to associate with the same name, you can put them into a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) and get each vector as `x{k}`.

You can use subscripts in axes labels, title and text annotations using Tex (default) or Latex interpretor. Use underscore character followed by subscript in a text string.

```
title('y = sin(x_k)')
```

or

```
title('y = sin(x_{several chars})')
```